Does DAX filter adhere to the sort by setting?
I have a calendar table with year week column having values like Y24 W1,... This column is sorted by YearWeekNumber (202401,...).
In DAX, for example, if I want to show sum of sales amt for all weeks on or after 2024 W5, then if I write:
CALCULATE(SUM(SALES['SALESAMT']),YEARWEEK>="Y24 W5")

Does the above YEARWEEK adhere to the sortby when evaluating the >= ?
In other words, does it include or exclude Y24 W10? If it adheres to sort by then it will include data for this week. Otherwise I beleive that Y24 W10 is alphabetically before Y24 W5.

If this is the way you are querying your data, you have a data modeling problem. You should not be querying a column containing a year and a week this way. Your YearWeek column should be something like 202405 and if you need a column containing a description, you should have a field named YearWeekDescription containing "Y24 W5".

No. In your case, it will sort alphabetically.
